# How to insert an element in DIV at position X Y

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to create a webpage where users can insert a pin (like google map) in
between the text using context menu.

My problem is that i do not know how to insert the pin at the exact position.
Using the DOM I can arrive only to the nearest DIV (by using **this**) but a DIV contains a
lot of text and the PIN has to be positioned next to the text.

I can obtain the position of the mouse click using pageX and pageY but
dont know how to insert an element at that position. I tried in JQuery: 
insertAfter, prepend, append but not getting the desired result.

Any idea how to solve this problem.

regards,
choesang tenzin

```
 $("#Content").rightClick( function(e) {

    $("<div class='pin'/>").insertAfter(this); 
 });
```

Comment: Shouldn't $("<div class='pin'/>").insertAfter(this); be $("div.pin").insertAfter(this); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks alot for all your ideas. I have come up with another way to do it. 
I am using the "RANGE" to insert directly into the clicked zone (div) and not after or before it and adding z-indexes. The positive points with this is:

1. It is really into the text and not as a layer
2. texts flow around the pin (text makes space for the pin)

   ```
   $("div").click( function(e) {
       //the following works only for FF at the moment          
       var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
       var pin = document.createElement('img');
       pin.setAttribute('src','pin_org.png');    
       pin.setAttribute('class','pin');                                                                    
       range.insertNode(pin);
   });           

   $("img.pin").live( 'mouseover', function () { 
   alert("hovered!!");
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#Content").rightClick( function(e) {
        var myTop = ...;
        var myRight= ...;
        $("<div class='pin' style='position:absolute; top: ' + myTop +'px; right: ' + myRight + 'px;/>").insertAfter(this); 
 });
```

sorry, i don't remember how to get x and y from the e parameter. Also, you will need to convert x,y of mouse click to x,y relative to #content element.

Comment: There's a couple of options for x/y and it's a bit of a x-browser mess. It's likely jquery wraps it nicely, but the native options are lsited here (mouse events only): http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position

Comment: thanks a lot it works!

$("#Content").rightClick( function(e) { 
  var x = e.pageX-5; 
  var y = e.pageY - 18;  
  $("<div class='pin' style='top: " + y + "px; left: " + x  + "px';></div>").insertAfter(this);   
  });

Answer (score 0):

Set the style `position:relaitve;` on the containing div, so that it becomes a layer. That way it works as origin for the absolutely positioned elements inside it.